# How to save states in Android using SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, state

How to save checkbox state in Android. 
Condition: if checkbox is checked, radiobuttons must be diabled and vise-versa.

```
 //More like an enable-disable button which should save 
  radioButtons states and then disable/enable them

 //RadioButtons states should be saved too
 //if radioeg1 was checked when checkbox was checked, its state should
     be saved     

 Eg.
  // cb = (Checkbox) findViewById(...) 
 //radioeg1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(...) 
 //radioeg2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(...)


if (cb.ischecked){

     //save cb state as checked

    //radioeg1.setEnabled(false) must be saved

   //radioeg2.setEnabled(false) must be saved

   //change the RadioButtons textcolor to grey? //Optional but an added Bonus if possible 
  //if not possible using this way, maybe change a textview's color to grey?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//On create check the state of checkbox

boolean checkBoxState = getSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("checkbox_state", false); //default unchecked

```
if(checkBoxState){
    checkbox.setChecked(true);
    radioeg1.setEnabled(false);
    radioeg1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

//store checkbox state when changed
    checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    editor.apply();
    editor.putBoolean("checkbox_state", isChecked);
    if (isChecked) {
        radioeg1.setEnabled(false);
        radioeg1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It's better to provide an explanation for the code!

Comment: I'm new to the concept, can you provide an explanation? What do I need to put in place of 'context'?

Comment: <CurrentActivityName>.this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (assuming `this` is of type `Context` or a subclass of `Context`) to save the checkbox state into SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences (this).edit();
```

This basically gets a `SharedPreferences.Edit` object which lets you edit the shared preferences. Now you can store stuff in it!

```
editor.putBoolean ("checkbox state", <Your boolean value here>);
```

Now you are done!

Um... not quite though... You still need to do something that I always forget! - `apply`ing the changes!

```
editor.apply();
```

Now you are *really* done.

To get the stuff out from shared preferences, first get a shared preference object: (Not an `Editor`!)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences (this);
```

Then you just call the `getXXX` method:

```
boolean checkBoxState = prefs.getBoolean ("checkbox state", false);
```

The first parameter is the key. You use the same key as the one that you used to save it i.e. `"checkbox state"`. The second parameter is what will be returned when it cannot find they key that you are looking for.

EDIT:

Oops! It seems like that I forgot the name of the method. It should be `getDefaultSharedPreferences` instead of `getSharedPreferences`. My bad!

You basically check the boolean variable `checkBoxState` to see whether to disable the radiobuttons or not.

```
if (checkBoxState) {
    //If it is true, disable the radiobuttons
    <Your radio button name>.setEnabled (false);
}
```

Comment: How do I link the radiobutton states with the checkbox? I'm new to the concept, can you also please provide details like what parts do I need to put in the onCreate()? I'm getting an error.. Non-static method getSharedPreferences() cannot be referenced from a static context. ( Your first code) I put it in the onCreate().

Comment: See my edited post @HarshwardhanS And do all my code in `onCreate` is ok

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences file;
private static int checkBox =1;
private static int radiobutton=0;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

In your OnCreate()
file = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editor=file.edit();
 if(file.getInt("checkBox",0)==0)
    {


        //disable radiobutton here;


    }

    if(file.getInt("radiobutton",1)==1)
    {


        //disable checkBox here;


    }
```

//you can put respective else also on the basis of your need what you are trying to do

```
Cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
    Cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            editor.putInt("checkBox", 0);


                editor.commit();
       }
   }
);  
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            editor.putInt("radiobutton", 1);


                editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

The overall idea of how to implement `Shared Preferences` in your problem might be clear from this.